# Importing XSD into WSDL error in target namespace

Tags: java, xsd, wsdl, cxf

Using `wsdl2java` from Apache CXF 4.0.3 I'm running into an error when trying to import XSD into my WSDL file. The files come from a 3rd party and with earlier versions of CXF the imports were working.

I've simplified the files down to the bare minimum to reproduce the problem. Here's the WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="https://webservices.sabre.com/websvc">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" schemaLocation="wsse.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
</definitions>
```

And this is the content of `wsse.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
</xs:schema>
```

When I run `wsdl2java`:

```
./wsdl2java -encoding UTF-8 -d /project/src/main/java -b "file:/project/src/main/resources/schema/custom-bindings/globalbinding.xjb" -p "=org.a.b.c" -suppress-generated-date -wsdlLocation classpath:schema/wsdl/sample.wsdl -verbose file:/project/src/main/resources/schema/wsdl/sample.wsdl
```

I get an error:

> org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException:
> file:///apache-cxf-4.0.3/bin/ [1,132]: the
> target namespace of the imported schema "" doesn't agree with the
> expected value "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext

The `targetNamespace` of `wsse.xsd` matches the `namespace` of the `xsd:import`. I don't see why the `targetNamespace` in the `definitions` element is relevant and I've seen plenty of examples of xsd imports where the `xsd:schema` element is missing a `targetNamespace`.

I've tried setting `targetNamespace` on `definitions` and `schema` but it doesn't change the error. If I change `targetNamespace` in the `wsse.xsd` file being imported I get a different error about a namespace mismatch between `xsd:import` and the file being imported.

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from the `-p "=org.a.b.c"` command line option.

From [documentation](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) :

> -p [ wsdl-namespace= ] PackageName
>
> Specifies zero, or more, package names to use for the generated code. Optionally specifies the WSDL namespace to package name mapping.

If you want to output generated code in `org.a.b.c` package, only set `-p "org.a.b.c"`, without `=` before packageName.